# How can I customize the color of the time headers in a Kendo UI Scheduler?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-template

Shown here is a good demo for kendo jquery scheduler 
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/index.html

My questions is : is it possible to modify the colors of the date header cells (i.e. cell on the left of each row that contains the date).. for example I want the first 8 hours to be colored as green, next eight red and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date header cell is shown in the toolbar on the top; what you're talking about are the time header cells.

I don't think there's a configuration option - you can try using the `majorTimeHeaderTemplate` like this:

```
window.colors = ["lightblue", "lightgreen", "lightgrey"];        
var template = "<div style='height:100%; width: 100%; background-color: " +
            "# var color = window.colors[Math.floor(date.getHours() / 8)]; # " +
    "#= color #;'><strong>#=kendo.toString(date, 'hh:mm')#</strong></div>";

$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
    majorTimeHeaderTemplate: kendo.template(template),
    dataSource: [{
        id: 1,
        start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
        end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
        title: "Interview"
    }]
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/HfS5e/))

Unfortunately you can't change the style of the container using the template, so if you don't like the whitespace, you'd have to modify the source code in `kendo.ui.DayView.fn._layout`; I'm only pasting the relevant excerpt here - the idea is to add  another class to the row depending on the hour:

```
this._forTimeRange(this.startTime(), this.endTime(), function (date, majorTick, middleRow, lastSlotRow) {
    var template = majorTick ? that.majorTimeHeaderTemplate : that.minorTimeHeaderTemplate;

    var colorClass = window.colors[Math.floor(date.getHours() / 8)];
    var row = {
        text: template({
            date: date
        }),
        className: lastSlotRow ? "k-slot-cell" : ""
    };
    row.className += colorClass; // we can then style the row using this selector

    rows.push(row);
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/HfS5e/3/))

You could use a similar approach for other view types.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much what I wanted. Is it possible to cover the entire time cell with the specified color (think of it as the complete cell with solid borders containing "11 am" colored with "lightblue" but without the surrounding white space)

Comment: not with the templates only - you'd need to try CodingWithSpike's solution (although it has the limitation that you can't color by hour, so when you want to use things like "show business hours", it might not work for you); the other alternative is to modify the source code of kendo.ui.DayView (I updated the answer)

Comment: @Abdelwahed did this work for you or do you still need help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with CSS. Something like:

```
.k-scheduler-times tr:nth-child(-n+8)
{
    background-color: green;
}

.k-scheduler-times tr:nth-child(n+9):nth-child(-n+16)
{
    background-color: red;
}
```